# R package: is there a method to generate a diagram of methods and dependencies in a package?

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm writing a package in R, defining a few S4 classes with inheritance and associated methods. I'd like to know if there's a package or method that would allow to automatically generate a flowchart summarizing classes, attributes and methods? Like some sort of ERD diagram?
Thank you.